# JSON serialize list of object with listposition C#

Tags: c#, json, list, serialization

Im trying to convert JSON data from an API to a List. This is what I get from the API:

```
{  
   "0":{  
      "Id":0,
      "FNr":"1",
      "Len":"1",
      "Typ":"1",
      "Sort":"1",
      "Low":"1",
      "Up":"1",
      "Rep":"1",
      "UC":"1",
      "Lo":"1",
      "Pf":"1",
      "SelP":"1",
      "Rel":"1",
      "RefLen":"1",
      "Description":"1",
      "Remarks":"1"
   },
   "1":{
      ...
   },
   "2":{
      ...
   }
}
```

Now I try to Deserialize this to a `List<DBTableEntryModel>`

```
var entries = JSON.Deserialize<List<DbTableEntryModel>>(jsonString);
```

This fails, because of the numbers. If I remove the numbers of the JSON string, it works perfectly fine. Is there a easier way to fix this issue, without splitting the JSON string?

This is my DBTableEntryModel:

```
public class DbTableEntryModel
    {
        [StringLength(3)]
        [ColumnWidth("30px")]
        public string FNr { get; set; }
        [StringLength(5)]
        [ColumnWidth("60px")]
        public string Len { get; set; }
        [StringLength(3)]
        [ColumnWidth("30px")]
        public string Typ { get; set; }
        [StringLength(3)]
        [ColumnWidth("35px")]
        public string Sort { get; set; }
        [StringLength(10)]
        [ColumnWidth("100px")]
        public string Low { get; set; }
        [StringLength(10)]
        [ColumnWidth("100px")]
        public string Up { get; set; }
        [StringLength(1)]
        [ColumnWidth("30px")]
        public string Rep { get; set; }
        [StringLength(1)]
        [ColumnWidth("25px")]
        public string UC { get; set; }
        [StringLength(1)]
        [ColumnWidth("25px")]
        public string Lo { get; set; }
        [StringLength(1)]
        [ColumnWidth("25px")]
        public string Pf { get; set; }
        [StringLength(2)]
        [ColumnWidth("34px")]
        public string SelP { get; set; }
        [ColumnWidth("90px")]
        public string Rel { get; set; }
        [ColumnWidth("90px")]
        public string RefLen { get; set; }
        [TextArea]
        [Display(Name = "Description", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Plugin))]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [TextArea]
        [Display(Name = "Remarks", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Plugin))]
        public string Remarks { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: could you please show your `DbTableEntryModel`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you still want to use list, you might try this.

```
var entries = JSON.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, DbTableEntryModel>>(jsonString).Select(x => x.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of deserializing your json into `List<DbTableEntryModel>` use `Dictionary<string, DbTableEntryModel>` like

```
var entries = JSON.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, DbTableEntryModel>>(jsonString);
```

Then you can use foreach loop to get all keys and entry from above dictionary like

```
foreach (var entry in entries)
{
     var key = entry.Key;                 //"0", "1", "2", ...
     var dbTableEntryModel = entry.Value; // Your `DbTableEntryModel` model
}
```